# yup validation comparing two number dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I'm trying to compare 2 number inputs with `yup` validation.

One of the names is `number1` and the other is `number2`.
number2 must be greater than or equal to number1 and number1 must be less than or equal to number2.

If I enter a 5 to `number1` and then I enter 4 to number 1 I am getting a `yup` validation error message as `number2` must be greater than or equal to 5". It is okay.
But if I change `number1` to 3 the error message still exists. Whereas in this case, `number1` is less than `number2`.
How can I manage these two input error messages dynamically with yup validation?

My validation schema:

```
validationSchema: {
            number1: yup
                .number()
                .required()
                .when('number2', (number2: any, schema: any) => {
                    if (number2) {
                        return schema.max(number2);
                    }
                }),
            number2: yup
                .number()
                .required()
                .when('number1', (number1: any, schema: any) => {
                    if (number1) {
                        return schema.min(number1);
                    }
                }),
        },
```

The error message I get
[inputs with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFhim.png)

I tried yup methods with using when or without when I also used ReactJs and React hook form.

I'm expecting that when I get an error message like the above if I change the other input all error messages disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

---

The problem has been solved but as I said above I'm using react-hook-form and the problem was related to react-hook-form. I had to add deps to Controller of these two inputs.

```html
<Controller
  rules={{
    deps: ['input2']
  }}
/>
```

Github url that I found the solution: https://github.com/orgs/react-hook-form/discussions/8633